# Differential equation $y'(t) = 1-y(t) e^{y(t)-1}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am interested in finding a clean explicit solution (if possible) to the differential equation

$$
y'(t) = 1-y(t) e^{y(t)-1},
$$
where $0 \le t < 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.
This can obviously be solved with direct integration, giving the solution

$$
t + C = \int \frac{1}{1-ye^{y-1}} dy.
$$

I have not found a solution to the integral, but that would essentially answer my question. I would like an expression for $y(t)$ that does not involve inverse functions. I tried finding a series solution but did not get very far.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question, and for sharing what you've tried so far.  Do you have a context for this problem?

Comment: Your integral definitely doesn't look elementary... [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s `integrate` just returns the same expression. So the hope for a solution like you are looking for is quite remote.

Comment: If you only want qualitative analysis, then the solution converges to the equilibrium solution $y(t)=1$ pretty fast by looking at the direction field(a visualization of dfield: http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/).

Comment: A series solution to the integral is actually given by $\frac{1}{1-ye^{y-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (ye^{y-1})^k$ for $ye^{y-1} < 1$

Comment: I think you are asking too much. Given a nonlinear ODE that does not come from a textbook, one can be almost sure that there's no clean explicit solution. I think the best strategy is to identify what you would use the exact solution for, and then achieve the same goal with approximate solutions.